# How to implement ScrollToTop in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed the documentation on how to implement ScrollToTop with React Router but I am unable to get the function to work. I created a component ScrollToTop.js with the following code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

In my App.js I add the wrapper after Router but all I get is a white screen whenever I call ScrollToTop. Here is a snippet from App.js.

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <AuthProvider>
     <GlobalStyles />
     <GoogleAnalytics />
     <CookiesNotification />
     <ScrollToTop>
        {renderRoutes(routes)}
     </ScrollToTop>
  </AuthProvider>
</Router>
```

I am told to wrap `<ScrollToTop` around `<App />` but that is not located in App.js but instead inside index.js in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScrollToTop` component does its job. I've set up a [working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-kmhg4?file=/src/App.js).

I have not changed `ScrollToTop` at all. The app looks like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Routes />
      <Links />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Now anytime the `Router`'s `pathname` changes, the app will scroll to the top.